# 'Polygon' object is not iterable- iPython Cookbook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, data-visualization, cartopy

I am learning visualization of data in python using `Cartopy`

I have this code for plotting Africa's population and GDP.

```py
def choropleth(ax, attr, cmap_name):
    # We need to normalize the values before we can
    # use the colormap.
    values = [c.attributes[attr] for c in africa]
    norm = Normalize(
        vmin=min(values), vmax=max(values))
    cmap = plt.cm.get_cmap(cmap_name)
    for c in africa:
        v = c.attributes[attr]
        sp = ShapelyFeature(c.geometry, crs,
                            edgecolor='k',
                            facecolor=cmap(norm(v)))
        ax.add_feature(sp)


fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(
    1, 2, figsize=(10, 16),
    subplot_kw=dict(projection=crs))
draw_africa(ax1)
choropleth(ax1, 'POP_EST', 'Reds')
ax1.set_title('Population')

draw_africa(ax2)
choropleth(ax2, 'GDP_MD_EST', 'Blues')
ax2.set_title('GDP')
```

And the expected output should be-
[image]

But I am getting an error as such -

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-41-b443c58ecbd5> in <module>
      3     subplot_kw=dict(projection=crs))
      4 draw_africa(ax1)
----> 5 choropleth(ax1, 'POP_EST', 'Reds')
      6 ax1.set_title('Population')
      7 

<ipython-input-40-161126226479> in choropleth(ax, attr, cmap_name)
      8     for c in africa:
      9         v = c.attributes[attr]
---> 10         sp = ShapelyFeature(c.geometry, crs,
     11                             edgecolor='k',
     12                             facecolor=cmap(norm(v)))

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cartopy/feature/__init__.py in __init__(self, geometries, crs, **kwargs)
    219         """
    220         super(ShapelyFeature, self).__init__(crs, **kwargs)
--> 221         self._geoms = tuple(geometries)
    222 
    223     def geometries(self):

TypeError: 'Polygon' object is not iterable
```

I tried searching for this issue on github but no to avail. Can anyone please help me out how can I correct this ?

Here is the [site](https://ipython-books.github.io/146-manipulating-geospatial-data-with-cartopy/) for reference .

Comment: This is the same error encountered in https://stackoverflow.com/q/63758107/13208790 have you tried the solutions in the answers there?

Comment: Yes I tried ..but its different @bystander

Comment: The cookbook where you took the lessons is now out-of-date. Today you can start with `geopandas` to do thematic mapping.

Comment: okay sure but I think there is problem with the cartopy syntax . How can I improve that ? @swatchai

Comment: If you want similar plots produced by `geopandas` (with cartopy supported)  in stead , you can ask as a new question referring to this question as being based on old code  (4+ years) that  used to work a few years ago.

Comment: If you want to just complete the exercise, the solution I posted with one of @swatchai's previous answers should solve it. But geopandas is preferred for this kind of work now.

Comment: Yes it worked . Thank you . I'll make sure to check geopandas

Comment: Great. If the solution works for you, you can mark it as accepted and ask any geopandas related stuff in a new questions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that the code tries to pass a shapely `Polygon` to a function that expects `MultiPolygon`. The elegant solution by swatchai here https://stackoverflow.com/a/63812490/13208790 is to catch `Polygon`s and put them in a list so they can be treated as `MultiPolygon`s.

Here's the code adapted to your case:

```
for i, c in enumerate(africa):
    v = c.attributes[attr]
    print(i)
    # swatchai's Polygon catch logic
    if c.geometry.geom_type=='MultiPolygon':
        # this is a list of geometries
        sp = ShapelyFeature(c.geometry, crs,
                        edgecolor='k',
                        facecolor=cmap(norm(v)))
    elif c.geometry.geom_type=='Polygon': 
        # this is a single geometry
        sp = ShapelyFeature([c.geometry], crs,
                                edgecolor='k',
                                facecolor=cmap(norm(v)))   
    else:
        pass  #do not plot the geometry
```

Comment: Typo: swatchai  :)

Comment: Then you need to edit again. Check comments in the code @swatchai

Comment: Thanks! And apologies for my clumsy typing swatchai