# TypeError: 'MultiPolygon' object is not iterable

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash, geopandas

I am trying to run the below script from plotly: https://plotly.com/python/county-choropleth/

I'm receiving the error code right out the gate: TypeError: 'MultiPolygon' object is not iterable

I've looked up several posts where this is a similar issue, but I'm skeptical these are solutions for this particular issue. OPTION 2 seems like the more likely approach, but why would there be a workaround for simple coding that plotly is publishing? Seems I might be missing something in the way the code is written.

OPTION 1: ['Polygon' object is not iterable- iPython Cookbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65124253/polygon-object-is-not-iterable-ipython-cookbook)

OPTION 2: [Python: Iteration over Polygon in Dataframe from Shapefile to color cartopy map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63758107/python-iteration-over-polygon-in-dataframe-from-shapefile-to-color-cartopy-map)

```
import plotly.figure_factory as ff

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df_sample = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/minoritymajority.csv')
df_sample_r = df_sample[df_sample['STNAME'] == 'Florida']

values = df_sample_r['TOT_POP'].tolist()
fips = df_sample_r['FIPS'].tolist()

endpts = list(np.mgrid[min(values):max(values):4j])
colorscale = ["#030512","#1d1d3b","#323268","#3d4b94","#3e6ab0",
              "#4989bc","#60a7c7","#85c5d3","#b7e0e4","#eafcfd"]
fig = ff.create_choropleth(
    fips=fips, values=values, scope=['Florida'], show_state_data=True,
    colorscale=colorscale, binning_endpoints=endpts, round_legend_values=True,
    plot_bgcolor='rgb(229,229,229)',
    paper_bgcolor='rgb(229,229,229)',
    legend_title='Population by County',
    county_outline={'color': 'rgb(255,255,255)', 'width': 0.5},
    exponent_format=True,
)
fig.layout.template = None
fig.show()
```

Comment: I didn't test/verify it, but based on the error possibly cartopy doesn't support shapely2 yet. I would try to install shapely<2 and look if that helps.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I downgraded down to shapely 1.8.5 and restarted my notebook kernel.  I'm not receiving an error any longer but the following is a short version of the output with no figure. Any ideas?

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/plotly/figure_factory/_county_choropleth.py:359: ShapelyDeprecationWarning:

Iteration over multi-part geometries is deprecated and will be removed in Shapely 2.0. Use the `geoms` property to access the constituent parts of a multi-part geometry.

Comment: It's odd that the figure isn't showing... anyway you can suppress the warning like this: import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same error message recently and came across this post. I think the key is the migration of shapely to 2.x. You need to use the ".gemos" attribute now to make multi-part geometries iterable:

https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/migration.html

This resolved my issue.

Answer (score 2):

Access the MultiPolygon's 'geoms' property.

https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/shapely.MultiPolygon.html#shapely.MultiPolygon

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34558679)

Comment: I didn't need to include the link at all. My answer remains: "Access the MultiPolygon's geoms property"

Answer (score 1):

Downgrade shapely to a lower version. Example:

```
pip3 install shapely==1.7.1
```

Versions>=2.0 giving error for me.